# WindowPhone 7.x | How to correctly close/pause video recording when app going to background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, video-capture, video-recording

When I lock my phone during video recording, my app hung with stack trace as below:

> System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.NativePhotoMethods.CapMan_Disconnect(int dwSeq)
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource.CaptureThread() + 0x2dd bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper(System.Threading.ThreadHelper t) + 0x1d bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0xb bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x63 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper() + 0x2a bytes

When I call `captureSource.Stop()` (on lock event [PhoneApplicationFrame.Obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), my app hang with different stack trace:

> mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.Join() 
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource.StopManagedImageCapture() + 0x3e bytes
>       System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource.Stop() + 0x10 bytes
>     HelloWorld.dll!HelloWorld.App.RootFrame_Obscured(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ObscuredEventArgs e) Line 96 + 0xa bytes   C#
>       Microsoft.Phone.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Frame.FireEventHandler(System.EventHandler handler, object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ObscuredEventArgs args) + 0xd bytes 
>       Microsoft.Phone.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.ShellPageManager_OnLockStateChange(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.LockStateChangeEventArgs args) + 0x48 bytes
>       Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.ShellPageManager.ShellPageCallback_OnLockStateChange(object source, Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.LockStateChangeEventArgs e) + 0x12 bytes
>       Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.ShellPageCallback.FireOnLockStateChange(bool fLocked) + 0x41 bytes
>       [External Code]

How can I prevent hanging and correctly pause/close the `CaptureSource`?

Answer (score -1):

Try implement the obscured Event for windows Phone

Here's [Obscured Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)'s link

This event is fired when the screen covers the app. Try Stopping / Pausingthe video then and there. See If it works. If not please leave a Reply

Comment: Actually I tried this. And in this case my app hangs in another place (you can see this in my question)

Comment: Did you try pausing it or stopping it ? Looks like a thread issue .

Comment: As I already said in the question `When I call captureSource.Stop() (on lock event PhoneApplicationFrame.Obscured), my app hang with different stack trace:`. [CaptureSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource(v=vs.95).aspx) haven't pause method.

Comment: try a work around by using Dispatcher Timer start it in obscure Event and call the Close() Method. May be calling it in a Different thread Might Just trying to figure out. Run The timer at about say 3-4 sec and stop it once it starts after calling close(). Please try and let me know If that works.

Comment: `DispatcherTimer` not helped me